# C++ – cURL cmd, stderr piped to program, very slow

Tags: c++, unix, curl, pipe, openframeworks

*Note: I'm using [openFrameworks](http://openframeworks.cc/about/), but I don't think it's required knowledge for understanding my problem here.*

### Overview

OSX 10.8.5

XCode 5.1.1

I have a program that `fork()`s, and the child process runs this cURL cmd:

```
curl -c cookies.txt -b cookies.txt -k https://www.space-track.org/ajaxauth/login -d 'identity=email@example.com&password=p4$$w0rd&query=https://www.space-track.org/basicspacedata/query/class/tle_latest/ORDINAL/1/EPOCH/%3Enow-30/orderby/OBJECT_ID/format/json' > ~/../myApp/bin/data/myData.json -#
```

This:

- Manages cookie file for [Space Track](https://www.space-track.org/) API
- Logs in with my Space Track account
- Downloads a dataset (~15,000 json objects) to "myData.json"
- Displays progress bar `######################################################################## 100.0%`

Child pipes the progress bar to parent, 1 char at a time. Parent simultaneously prints progress bar to console. Below is the entire `fork()` portion of my code:

**.h** (relevant global vars)

```
{
    bool forkOnce, isBufferFull;
    int childToParentPipe[2]; // Child to parent pipe. [0] = read (output), [1] = write (input)
    char ch;
    int pid, outCount;
    string buffer; 
}
```

**.cpp**

```
if(!forkOnce){ //we're in an ∞ loop, so we need to control the flow

    //make pipe
    if( pipe(childToParentPipe) < 0){
        perror("Can't make pipe");
        _exit(1);
    }

    //vars for dealing w piped chars
    buffer = ""; // string that holds 1 line of progress meter
    isBufferFull = false; // is ^ buffer string full?
    outCount = 0; //counts chars coming from pipe (for carriage returns)

    cout << "Forking..." << endl;
    pid = fork();
}
switch(pid){
    case -1:{
        perror("Can't fork");
        _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        break;
    }
    case 0:{ // child

        if(!forkOnce){ // do child stuff once

            close(2); // Close current stderr
            dup( childToParentPipe[1]); //Make stderr go to write end of pipe
            close( childToParentPipe[0]); //Close read end of pipe because it's not needed in child process

            //make output file for stdout
            int out = creat("/.../myApp/bin/data/myData.json", S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);

            if (out == -1){
                perror("Can't make file");
                _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            } else { //if file successfully created
                dup2(out,STDOUT_FILENO);// redirect stdout to the file                
                execlp( [the curl command goes here] , NULL); // exec the command
                close(out); // close file
                _exit(0);

            }
        }
        break;
    }
    default:{ // parent

        close(childToParentPipe[1]);

        //while num bytes piped out is 1 (meaning we haven't reached EOF yet)
        if( read(childToParentPipe[0], &ch, 1) == 1) {

            if(outCount == 80){
                isBufferFull = true;
                outCount = 0;
            }

            if(!isBufferFull){
                buffer += ch;
            } else {
                char* bufferChars = strdup(buffer.c_str());
                bufferChars[outCount] = ch;
                buffer = bufferChars;
            }

            cout << buffer << endl;

            outCount++;
        }

        // wait for child process
        int status = 0;
        waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG);
        //printf("child status:%d\n",status); // "0"

        signal(SIGCHLD,signalHandler); //signalHandler = func that finalizes this process

        break;
    }
}

forkOnce = true;
```

### Problems

The cURL download is extremely slow in my app compared to running it in Terminal:

[image]

...and sometimes, in my app, this error is printed to console a few times during download:

```
2015-12-18 15:44:16.595 forkTest2Debug[22858:5f1f] -[NSPersistentUIManager writeWindowSnapshot:length:width:height:bytesPerRow:toFile:inDirectory:encryptingWithKey:uuid:checksum:isUserWaitingImpatientlyForThisThingToFinish:]: 0 == ftruncate(fd, finalFileSize) failed on line 2770: Bad file descriptor
```

Can't figure out why I'd get a `Bad file descriptor` error. I can't seem to find any official documentation regarding `isUserWaitingImpatientlyForThisThingToFinish` or `ftruncate` that informs me in this context.

My app runs 60fps so the output from the pipe pumps out chars at that rate. Might this be filling up my pipe, as chars get fed into it faster than they get fed out?

**What is causing this slowness and how can I fix it?**

Comment: Why don't you use *libcurl* instead of forking and calling `curl` from the command line? Also, this is [tag:c++] not [tag:c]

Comment: I tried using libcurl but this seemed like the easier path. Now that I've gone this far I'd prefer to finish it this way.

Comment: 1. *libcurl* is not hard at all (except if you use the *mutli* interface). 2. Why on earth don't you use [`popen()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html)?

Comment: I'm not an experienced programmer and this took me a whole month to put together lol. I honestly couldn't figure out where to even begin with libcurl (I've been through all the documentation many times). Please, I'd like to finish it this way.

Comment: Then use `popen()`. May I ask why are you doing this in [tag:c].

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example of [`popen()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html), this might help you do it the way you want

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char output[100];
    char command[100];
    ssize_t length;
    FILE *pipe;
    if (argc < 2)
        return -1; // Missing command line parameters
    if (snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "curl %s", argv[1]) >= sizeof(command))
        return -1; // URL too long
    pipe = popen(command, "r");
    if (pipe == NULL)
        return -1; // Execution failure
    while ((length = fread(output, 1, sizeof(output), pipe)) > 0)
        fwrite(output, 1, length, stdout);
    pclose(pipe);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and test like this

```
$ gcc -Wall -Werror -g3 -O0 SOURCE.c -o _curl_test
$ ./_curl_test http://stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: Okay. I will try this. Thanks. Since I know this will take a long time figuring out what's going on here and how to incorporate this into my code, in the meantime, do you happen to know what is causing the slowness in the work I had already done, as per my original question?

Comment: ...and could you explain how using `popen()` instead will solve the problem? Thanks again.